# Having trouble hiding and unhiding divs within CSS

Tags: html, css

There might be a really simple answer to my question but I'm having difficulties getting something that I thought pretty simple to work.
On the load of my website I set a div with the visibility to hidden:

```
<div id="BottomBarContainer" class="BottomBarContainer" style="visibility:hidden;">
 <div class="BottomBarLeft"><img style='height:100%; width:100%; object-fit: contain' src="images/BottomBarLeft.gif" title="Bottom Bar"/></div> 
 <div class="BottomText1"></div>
 <div class="BottomText1"><br><br>
     <span style="font-family: Calibri; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 10pt; color:white;"><a href="index.asp">About Us</a></span><br><br><BR>
     <span style="font-family: Calibri; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 10pt; color:white;">Contact Us</span><br><br><BR>
     <span style="font-family: Calibri; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 10pt; color:white;">Location</span>
 </div>
```

then in my CSS I check if the max-width drop below 900px when the screen is resized, if so I hide one div and then try to show the hidden one. Hiding the visible div works fine but I cannot get the hidden div to become visible.
This is my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.BottomBarContainer {display:block;visibility:visible; }
.floatdiv { display: none; }  
.MiddlePicContainer {display:none; }
#myRotator {display:none; }
#HiddenDiv { display:block; visibility:visible;}
```

}

I have tried multiple ways to get the desired result; using display:none instead of setting the visibility when hiding, moving the visibility into the BottomBarContainer class, all these work to hide the div, just can't get it back visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify the attribute in class `.BottomBarContainer`  instead of doing it in by using inline style attribute. Below a Snippet improved of your code.

#### Snippet

```css
.BottomBarContainer {
  visibility: hidden;
}
span {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: white;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .BottomBarContainer {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .floatdiv {
    display: none;
  }
  .MiddlePicContainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #myRotator {
    display: none;
  }
  #HiddenDiv {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="BottomBarContainer" class="BottomBarContainer">
  <div class="BottomBarLeft">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/900/300" title="Bottom Bar" />
  </div>
  <div class="BottomText1"></div>
  <div class="BottomText1">
    <br />
    <br />
    <span><a href="index.asp">About Us</a></span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Contact Us</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Location</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help, I have made the changes you recommended bust its still not working. Could you have a quick look below and see where i'm going wrong? My code now looks like this:
<div id="BottomBarContainer" class="BottomBarContainer"> .......</div> 

And the CSS looks like this:
.BottomBarContainer {
    visibility:hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .BottomBarContainer {
     visibility:visible;
     }
    .floatdiv { 
     display: none;
     }   
    .MiddlePicContainer {
     display:none; 
     }    
    #myRotator {
    display:none; 
    }
}

Comment: Not sure what it hasn't formatted my code but i'm sure you can get the idea. thanks.

Comment: Forget that! I got it working, thank you ... it seems to have something to do with the order of the class definitions if the CSS. Moved the #BottomBarContainer to top, moved the @media to the bottom and it started working. Thank you very much for your help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you specified `visiblitiy:hidden` using the style attribute. The style attribute overrides everything else. Move that out to your CSS definition and you should be fine.